# How to save UIView with subviews without losing quality?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiimage

I am trying to save the view with its subview, but the saved image is little bit blurry (especially the label's text)

I tried all the solutions given in stackoverflow - no use.

Can anyone help me on the same?

I am using the below code

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, 0);        
    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];        
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();        
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

[image]

And getting the blurred text, also the picture quality is low.

Comment: Hello Bala, if you share with us what you've tried so far, it would be easier to find a solution to your problem. Which solutions did you try? Are you snapshotting the view? Shortly, show us the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a higher resolution image. It should be fine if you compress a high resolution image to down, but scaling up a low resolution image to a larger size will generally blur the image contents, as it stretches everything.

Comment: I am having UILabel and its text. I am saving my entire screen as a image, the result image is shows low quality blurry text(i modified my question with more info now).

Answer (score 0):

The preferred approach is `[UIView snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:]`. You should only use `drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:` if you plan to apply additional effects.

That said, there are several likely causes, depending on how you're manipulating or saving the image. For example, saving text in JPEG format will cause blurriness. Rotating or scaling the image without great care can make the text blurry. Drawing the image incorrectly (for instance, failing to pixel-align it) can make the text blurry. You should simplify your problem if you're making multiple steps, and validate the quality at each step. To discuss it further on StackOverflow, you need to provide details on how you're manipulating and displaying the image, not just how you generate it.

Text is extremely susceptible to artifacts. If you must take pictures of it (something you generally should avoid if at all possible), you should make sure to manipulate it as little as possible. It is always better to manipulate the text before it's drawn rather than after.

Comment: Thanks Napier, I am having a container view. Container view is having one image view (its size is the parent container view's size) on top of the image view there is one UILabel which is rotated in vertical.  So, i can able to change the image and text of the lable.  Now i want to save the image along with the text which i changed.  If i use the above code, i can able to see the low quality image and blurry text.

Comment: Have you tried the preferred snapshotView API? This is what it's for. You didn't explain any of the other things I asked, particularly what you're doing with the image after you snapshot it. Do you manipulate it at all? How are you viewing it? Is the resulting image 2x the screens size (since it's Retina?) In general id prefer to solve this problem by just drawing the image and text by hand into an image context of the desired size rather than using snapshots of drawn views.

Comment: after the snapshot i am saving it into the photo gallery without doing anything. this is the code i am using to save the image   ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[etagImage CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[etagImage imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
        
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];